# Flash crashing across all browsers

Tags: windows, google-chrome, firefox, flash

I just fresh installed Windows 10 and downloaded the latest Flash. However, any page that uses Flash, like YouTube, crashes. This goes for all browsers.

Chrome gives me this error:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/edaDuzk.png]

Firefox gives me this error:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/oNMGzkr.png]

I've tried reinstalling Flash, but that didn't seem to help. What can I do to fix this?